# setting enum value to 1 on link click?

Tags: php, mysql

can someone please help, i am trying to get the column 'privellages' (i know its spelt wrong) to update in my table 'ptb_permissions' when a link is clicked.

basically i've done this before for loads of other things and its worked fine its just this not working for some reason.

users are notified in their inbox when a user sends a request to view their pictures. and the user will have two links one to approve or one to delete the request.

if they click approve then this should update the enum colum 'privellages' from 0 to 1.

this is not working. im not getting any errors im just not getting anything happening. please can someone show me where im going wrong thanks.

```
<a href="includes/approve_priv_pix.php?pix=<?php echo $pix['user_id']; ?>">Yes this is ok</a>
```

contents of approve_priv_pix.php;

```
<?php
require_once("session.php"); 
require_once("functions.php");
require('_config/connection.php');
approve_pix ($_GET['picture'], $_SESSION['user_id']);
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
?>
```

mysql function:

```
function approve_pix($picture, $user) {
                        global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
                        $query = "UPDATE ptb_permissions
                                    SET privellages='1'
                                    WHERE id=$picture 
                                    AND to_user_id=$user";
            mysql_query($query, $connection);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['picture']` should be `$_GET['pix']`

Also double check your `privellages` column enum values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="includes/approve_priv_pix.php?pix=<?php echo $pix['user_id']; ?>">Yes this is ok</a>
```

Here you have `pix` as a key, but in  approve_priv_pix.php you are taking picture id from `$_GET['picture']`. Suppose it should be replaced with `$_GET['pix']`
Also, not sure why do you have `<?php echo $pix['user_id']; ?>` in link code. Possibly it should be something like `<?php echo $pix['picture_id']; ?>`

Additionally, you code is opened to sql injections. Here:

```
$query = "UPDATE ptb_permissions
          SET privellages='1'
          WHERE id=$picture 
          AND to_user_id=$user";
```

Instead of that you should better do:

```
$query = "UPDATE ptb_permissions
          SET privellages='1'
          WHERE id=" .mysql_real_escape_string($picture) . "
          AND to_user_id=" .mysql_real_escape_string($user);
```

More details about [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Take a look at warning message on top of that page. mysql extension is deprecated and will be remove soon. For new projects you should better use PDO or MySQLi extensions.

Another note:  `global $_SESSION;` is not needed at all. It is accessible form any place in PHP by default.

> im not getting any errors im just not getting anything happening

To see all errors you should set [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to E_ALL (in your ini file or directly in code). With this option enabled you would see all notices/warnings/errors.